# An intuitive idea about the limit of a continuous function: Is it correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let's assume that we have a function $f(x)$ whose limit at $c$ is given as $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = f(c)$, such that it is continuous at $c$. For this limit, we have left and right side limits $\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \to c^-}f(x) = f(c)$.

Intuitively, one thinks that since the left and right side limits exist, for both the left and right sides of $c$, there should be some real numbers $\delta_{left}$ and $\delta_{right}$ such that $f(x)$ is nondecreasing or nonincreasing on the intervals $(\delta_{left},c)$ and $(c,\delta_{right})$. The logic is, that $f(x)$ gets continuously nearer to $f(c)$,when we go from $\delta_{left}$ to $c$ or when we go from $\delta_{right}$ to $c$, which is an intuitive thought when one thinks about the limit, before seeing the $(\epsilon,\delta)$ definition.

I am not able to find a counterexample to that. If a limit exists, the function have to "move" to that limit after some distance. Is this really a correct thing that can be proven or is it not correct? And why it is not correct, if so?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question, but $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2}) = 0$, but the function oscillates infinitely up and down as it approaches $0$ (it just oscillates less and less as it gets closer).

Comment: Thanks, that is actually what I was asking. It is an example for a function which gets closer to the limit without being monotonously increasing or decreasing after a while.

Comment: No you are wrong since the definition of limit says that your $\delta$ can be made arbitrary small. This is what I remember.

Comment: I'm not sure who that's directed towards, but given any interval $(0, \delta)$, no matter how small, $x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ will oscillate an infinite amount of times on that interval.

Comment: I made an edit to my question, I forgot to add the fact that $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$.

Comment: If $f(x)$ being continuous at $c$ is a condition, then we can modify my counterexample to be equal to $x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $0$ for $x = 0$. This makes it continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've stated in the comments, a counterexample is $$\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$$

We can make this continuous if we say the function is $x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ for $x = 0$.

For any interval $(0, \delta)$ or $(-\delta, 0)$ that we pick, no matter how small $\delta$ is, then that interval will contain infinitely many oscillations.  Notice that if $x = \sqrt{\frac{2}{n\pi}}$, then we have $x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2}) = \frac{2}{n\pi} \sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}).$ For odd $n$, this will be either a peak or a valley for the graph. Note that there are *infinitely* many $x$ like this on any interval you choose.

Comment: Good example, thank you.